# issue with ionic bundle library load and ngcordova library load using require js

Tags: cordova, requirejs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic.bundle.js and ngcordova.js in my application.
I am using require js for loading the above libraries.

I am getting below error "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined",

Below is how is code:
**main.js**

```
 require.config({
      paths: {
          'ionic': '/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle',
          'ngCordova' : '/lib/ng-cordova',

      },
      shim: {
          ngcordova: {
            deps: ['ionic']
          }
      },
     // baseUrl: '/app'
    });

require(['app'], function (app) {
  app.init();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(['ionic', 'ngCordova'], function (ionic, ngCordova) {
    //'use strict';

    //var ionic = require('ionic');
    //var ngcordova = require('ngCordova');

    var appModule = angular.module("ePharma", ["ngCordova", "ionic"]);


    appModule.init = function () {
        alert("hi");
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ePharma']);
    };

    return appModule;
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to export angular in your shim.

```
shim: {
    'ionic': { exports: ['angular'] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this same approach using Ionic with RequireJS when I found this link on Ionic forums: [Ionic and AngularJS dependency](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-and-angularjs-dependency/5894)

There, @bengtler explains that he doesnt use the bundle js file, instead he uses separated ionic and angular files that you can get at http://code.ionicframework.com and shim them in the require.js configuration.

Here's what the config looks like:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'app',
paths: {
    'angular': '../lib/angular.min',
    'angular_ionic': '../lib/ionic-angular.min'
    ...
},
shim: {
    'angular' : { 'exports' : 'angular' },
    'angular_ionic': [...]
},
priority: [
    'angular',
    'angular-ionic'
],
callback: function () {
    'use strict';

    require([
        'angular',
        'routes'
    ], function (angular) {
        // init app
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
}});
```

I also just asked him there if this approach is still whats he's using and what changes he would make today since its a topic from 2014.
You might already have found a solution for it, but its always good to see more opinions about it.